# Tuning a LASSO model and predicting using tidymodels

Tags: r, machine-learning, lasso-regression, tidymodels

I want to perform penalty selection for the LASSO algorithm and predict outcomes using `tidymodels`. I will use the Boston housing dataset to illustrate the problem.

```
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)
library(mlbench)

data("BostonHousing")

dt <- BostonHousing
```

I first split the dataset into train/test subsets.

```
dt_split <- initial_split(dt)
dt_train <- training(dt_split)
dt_test <- testing(dt_split)
```

Defining preprocessing using the `recipe` package.

```
rec <- recipe(medv ~ ., data = dt_train) %>%
  step_center(all_predictors(), -all_nominal()) %>% 
  step_dummy(all_nominal()) %>% 
  prep()
```

Initialization of the model and the workflow. I use the `glmnet` engine. `mixture = 1` means that I choose the LASSO penalty and `penalty = tune()` means that I will later use cross-validation to choose the best penalty parameter `lambda`.

```
lasso_mod <- linear_reg(mode = "regression",
                        penalty = tune(),
                        mixture = 1) %>% 
  set_engine("glmnet")

wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(lasso_mod) %>%
  add_recipe(rec)
```

Preparing stratified 5-fold cross-validation and the penalty grid:

```
folds <- rsample::vfold_cv(dt_train, v = 5, strata = medv, nbreaks = 5)
my_grid <- tibble(penalty = 10^seq(-2, -1, length.out = 10))
```

Let us run the cross-validation:

```
my_res <- wf %>% 
  tune_grid(resamples = folds,
            grid = my_grid,
            control = control_grid(verbose = FALSE, save_pred = TRUE),
            metrics = metric_set(rmse))
```

I'm now able to get the best penalty from the grid and update my workflow for this optimal penalty:

```
best_mod <- my_res %>% select_best("rmse")
print(best_mod)

final_wf <- finalize_workflow(wf, best_mod)
print(final_wf)

== Workflow ===================================================================================================================
Preprocessor: Recipe
Model: linear_reg()

-- Preprocessor ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 Recipe Steps

* step_center()
* step_dummy()

-- Model ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Linear Regression Model Specification (regression)

Main Arguments:
  penalty = 0.0278255940220712
  mixture = 1

Computational engine: glmnet
```

So far so good. Now I want to apply the workflow to the training data to get my final model:

```
final_mod <- fit(final_wf, data = dt_train) %>%
  pull_workflow_fit()
```

**Now here is the issue.**

`final_mod$fit` is a `elnet` and `glmnet` object. It contains the full regularization path on a grid of 75 values of the penalty parameter. Hence the previous penalty tuning step is pretty much useless. So the prediction step fails:

`predict(final_mod, new_data = dt)` returns an error:

```
Error in cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta : 
  invalid class 'NA' to dup_mMatrix_as_dgeMatrix
```

Of course I could use `glmnet::cv.glmnet` to get the best penalty and then use the method `predict.cv.glmnet` but I need a generic workflow able to work with multiple machine learning models using the same interface. In the [documentation](https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/linear_reg.html) of `parsnip::linear_reg` there is this note regarding the glmnet engine:

> For glmnet models, the full regularization path is always fit
> regardless of the value given to penalty. Also, there is the option to
> pass multiple values (or no values) to the penalty argument. When
> using the predict() method in these cases, the return value depends on
> the value of penalty. When using predict(), only a single value of the
> penalty can be used. When predicting on multiple penalties, the
> multi_predict() function can be used. It returns a tibble with a list
> column called .pred that contains a tibble with all of the penalty
> results.

However, I do not understand how I should proceed to get the predictions of the tuned LASSO model using the `tidymodels` framework. The `multi_predict` function throws the same error as `predict`.

Comment: Please update your question to include the exact error returned by `predict(final_mod, new_data = dt)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are really close here to having everything working right.

Let's read in the data, split it into training/testing and create resampling folds.

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)
library(mlbench)

data("BostonHousing")

dt <- BostonHousing

dt_split <- initial_split(dt)
dt_train <- training(dt_split)
dt_test <- testing(dt_split)
folds <- vfold_cv(dt_train, v = 5, strata = medv, nbreaks = 5)
```

Now let's create a preprocessing recipe. (Notice that you don't need to `prep()` it if you are using a `workflow()`; that can get slow if your data is big so might as well not do it until the `workflow()` takes care of it for you later.)

```r
rec <- recipe(medv ~ ., data = dt_train) %>%
    step_center(all_predictors(), -all_nominal()) %>% 
    step_dummy(all_nominal())
```

Now let's make our model, put it together with our recipe in a `workflow()`, and tune the workflow with a grid.

```r
lasso_mod <- linear_reg(mode = "regression",
                        penalty = tune(),
                        mixture = 1) %>% 
    set_engine("glmnet")

wf <- workflow() %>%
    add_model(lasso_mod) %>%
    add_recipe(rec)

my_grid <- tibble(penalty = 10^seq(-2, -1, length.out = 10))

my_res <- wf %>% 
    tune_grid(resamples = folds,
              grid = my_grid,
              control = control_grid(verbose = FALSE, save_pred = TRUE),
              metrics = metric_set(rmse))
```

This is the best penalty we got:

```r
best_mod <- my_res %>% select_best("rmse")
best_mod
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   penalty .config              
#>     <dbl> <chr>                
#> 1  0.0215 Preprocessor1_Model04
```

Here is where we do things a little bit differently than what you did. I am going to **finalize** my workflow with the best penalty and then **fit** that finalized workflow to the training data. The output here is a **fitted workflow**. I do not want to pull the underlying model out of this, because the model *needs* the preprocessing to work correctly; it was trained expecting the preprocessing to happen.

Instead, I can just `predict()` straight on that trained workflow:

```r
final_fitted <- finalize_workflow(wf, best_mod) %>%
    fit(data = dt_train)

predict(final_fitted, dt_train)
#> # A tibble: 379 x 1
#>    .pred
#>    <dbl>
#>  1  18.5
#>  2  24.2
#>  3  23.3
#>  4  21.6
#>  5  37.6
#>  6  21.5
#>  7  16.7
#>  8  15.6
#>  9  21.3
#> 10  21.3
#> # … with 369 more rows
predict(final_fitted, dt_test)
#> # A tibble: 127 x 1
#>    .pred
#>    <dbl>
#>  1  30.2
#>  2  25.1
#>  3  19.6
#>  4  17.0
#>  5  13.9
#>  6  15.4
#>  7  13.7
#>  8  20.8
#>  9  31.1
#> 10  21.3
#> # … with 117 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

If you tune a workflow, then you generally want to finalize, fit, and predict a workflow. Exceptions might be if you use a really simple preprocessor in your workflow like a formula that you can pass to `fit()`; I [show an example that you could do that with here](https://juliasilge.com/blog/datasaurus-multiclass/).